# How to describe leaves growing

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a nice way or fancy word to describe the new growing of leaves on a tree?

The word I'm looking for is something like "Leafing" or "Foliaging". I've also come across this, which to me sounds even more ridiculous: [Leaf-out or Bud-out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76454/is-there-a-noun-verb-for-the-process-of-growing-new-leaves-on-a-tree).

Any other cool words or creative options to express this?

Comment: the references in your question are nice and correct answers.

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Cambridge dictionary defines the term *to sprout*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sprout) as:

> to produce leaves, hair, or other new developing parts, or (of leaves, hair, and other developing parts) to begin to grow

[Example from OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sprout), found under example sentence 1.2:

> ‘With the first rains, leaves sprout on trees and bushes and the savannah grass grows to several yards within a few months.’

Comment: I think that's the most straightforward. Sprout or blossoming, perhaps with the edge to sprout.

Answer (score 3):

Spring [**unfurled**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unfurl) the trees their leaves, to shake in the breeze and bask in the sun.

> **unfurl** (*verb*) ~ Make or become spread out from a rolled or folded state, especially in order to be open to the wind.
>
> *with object*: ‘a man was unfurling a sail’
>
> *no object*: ‘the flags unfurl’

[Leaves Unfurling](https://www.google.com/search?q=leaves%20unfurling&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlyu-Lo_LZAhVHHGMKHaQuBmQQsAQIKA&biw=1280&bih=590)

[image]

[image: leaves unfurling vs trees unfurling]

[image: wake up time]

> 明 佚名 貍奴芭蕉圖 冊頁
>   Frolicking Kittens under a Banana **Tree**
>
> Kittens in a garden setting was a favorite subject of Academy painters during the Song dynasty. Here, the young ones play while the mother watches. New banana plants and shoots, their leaves not yet [**unfurled**](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/45667?sortBy=Relevance&ft=unfurling&offset=0&rpp=20&pos=9), have just emerged, but a sprig of bamboo visible along the right-hand margin of the painting is still without its summer greenery.

This Washington State University presentation on Leaf Index Management specifically uses the word [**unfurl**](http://slideplayer.com/slide/6107302/) six times, relevant to leaves on **grapevines**.

- The ubiquitous **unfurling** of leaves, Spring's triumphant green flag.

Comment: With unfurling I also think of something that may exist previously (i.e., is not a new growth) and changes its structuring or positioning: like unfurling towards the sun in a heliotropic way during the daytime.

Comment: @user1383058 Your question asked for **a nice way or fancy word** to express it, and now you've changed your mind and want something scientific or technical?

Comment: This seems to be specific to certain leaves, [so-called fronds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frond), which are leaves with divisions in them. It's a nice word though.

Comment: @JJJ it's not specific to fronds. Read the quote from Chief Seattle that I posted in my answer. You could also try the link I provided, which shows all kinds of lush greenery (including trees).

Comment: @Bread I'm not sure if quoting someone who had to be translated twice to be understood is a good source for English language matters: ["Chief Seattle most probably spoke in the Lushootseed language, and someone then translated his words into Chinook Jargon, a limited trading language, which a third person then translated that into English. "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Seattle#The_oldest_version:_1887)

Comment: @JJJ So your suggesting the English translator didn't know the proper use of the word unfurl.

Comment: @Bread I am saying different words have different meanings in different languages, not every word in one language is defined in another language, and in different languages definitions for similar words differ.  Even within a language, especially a tribal one, words can even have different meanings (think of biscuit in AmE and BrE). Let alone if it had to be translated twice, some context or nuance would be lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74668/discussion-between-bread-and-jjj).

Answer (score 1):

It repeatedly defies my attempts to see it happening; but, trees' branch-ends begin to swell ever so slowly with the spring rain.
Now, when this "*budding*" happens, if I don't immediately stop what I'm doing to stare intently at them trying not to blink, I'll *miss* how the swollen buds ***open*** appearing to ***explode*** and expand into mature leaves.